# How to capture just words in a string line

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture only proper words from a string line using regex (i.e. points, commas, parenthesis, etc... are not desired). For example, if the input line is:

```
So she was considering in her own mind (as well as she could),
```

I would like to capture:

```
So 
she 
was 
considering 
in
....
```

Does anybody knows a way to do this? I'm new to regex unfortunately :S

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the regex you need:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]+\b
```

[See demo](http://regex101.com/r/tI4bS0).

**Explanation**

- `\b` is a word boundary that matches a position where one side is a letter, and the other side is not a letter (for instance a space character, or the beginning of the string)
- The character class `[a-zA-Z]` matches one character in the ranges `a-z` and `A-Z`
- The `+` quantifier says that we must match what precedes one or more times
- The `\b` boundary ensures that our word is finished. Together the two boundaries ensure we have a complete word.

**In Java**

In the comments, you mentioned that you'd like to see a list. You can use this:

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\b[a-z]+\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
    }
```

Note that I made the pattern case-insensitive.

Comment: Great! It indeed works... one question, what if I want to have all the  words as a list. I mean, I do want to avoid parenthesis, commas, etc... but I would like to get the words separately. To put in context, I'm using java's split method so I would like to print out all the words that compose a line. Cheers!

Comment: I added Java code so you can get a list. Let me know if it works on your side. :)

Comment: Wouldn't `line.split(/(?:[^a-zA-Z]|\s)+/)` work? Just inverts the match: "find but don't keep a non-zero number of non-alphabetic or whitespace characters". Had to go make sure Java non-capture was the same as Perl's.

Comment: @JoeMcMahon Hey, what's up with the huge edits you tried to make on my answer? There are always a 100 ways to do the same thing. Yes, matching and splitting are two sides of the same coin. nelt22 started asking for a list, that's how I answered. You're entirely free to show a different way, and if it works I'll upvote it (pls provide demo) as I always like to see alternative answers. :)

Comment: Thanks, see you next time! :)

Comment: Since you has said you'd explain later, and it had been a while, thought I'd help out by adding the detailed description. Sorry if I barged in too early...!

Comment: @JoeMcMahon Thanks for explaining. :) I don't blame you for liking things clean and tidy. Wishing you a great weekend.